# Google Cloud Platform OCR on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

Since the Google Cloud Platform vision on iOS only supports Face Recognition for now.
Is it another way to use google cloud platform api Optical Character Recognition (OCR) on iOS?

Best wishes,

David

Answer (score -1):

You can use the rest API [1] as there are no libraries for objective-C.

A POST request example:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
         "imageUri": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.dataturks.test/testocr.png"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/